# Overlaying Exchange "Resources" (not personal calendars)-OR-Inviting from exchange linked sharepoint calendar

Tags: exchange, overlay

I currently have multiple resource calendars in outlook that I want to overlay onto a master SharePoint calendar for ease of viewing at staff meetings etc. All of my research indicates this is not possible and that only the logged in user can be overlayed from Exchange. Is this true?

1. if the above is **NOT** true, what is my work around?
2. assuming the above **IS** true, I set up and linked a SharePoint resource calendar to Outlook successfully, but cannot invite it from outlook, or invite people from it. Does this functionality exist? I have seen SharePoint Online tools for this function, (see [sharepointsapiens](http://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/calendar-events-invites-add-in-now-available-for-sharepoint-online/) tutorial but I am still On Premise and will not convert to Online for quite some time.

Bottom line-I want my users to be able to schedule a full Meeting (invitees, room etc) on EITHER outlook OR SharePoint and have them update one another. Is it possible?

Comment: welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution